# Using Continuous web pages

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, web

I have a website, in which the images are continuously changing after some time. But instead of images i want to put website page which will continuously change and refresh also for latest data.

### CODE:

```
<div class="bannerbg">
        <div class="container clearfix">
                <div class="flexslider" >
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/fslide01.jpg" alt="" />
                        <p class="flex-caption">I am Caption!</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/fslide02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/fslide03.jpg" alt="" />
                        <p class="flex-caption">I am Caption!</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/fslide04.jpg" alt="" />
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <img src="images/fslide05.jpg" alt="" />
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <img src="images/fslide06.jpg" alt="" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Slider -->
```

---

Instead of these images fslide01/02/03/04/05/06.jpg i want to use webpages like www.yahoo.com/www.facebook.com/www.google.com/etc and i should refresh also for latest view.

Comment: Pages are from external sites or pages from your website ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `iframes`, though some sites (such as Google) disallow displaying their site in an iframe. I would imagine other popular sites would do the same.

```
<li>
    <iframe src="somesite.com/index.html"></iframe>
    <p class="flex-caption">I am Caption!</p>
</li>
```

MDN Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: @SuryaGupta You can change the appearance of the iframe via CSS. I usually end up doing something like this: `border-width:0px;position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;`

Comment: Suppose i have 100*100 space to show my images fslides01/02..etc, but the above script is showing webpage only in 25*25 space with scrolls.. but i want the complete page on 100*100 space without any scroll

Comment: @SuryaGupta You would use either inline styles (ex: `iframe.style.width="100px"`) or an external stylesheet to do this. To remove the scroll, you would set the `overflow` property to `none`.